# Http tp Https URL re-write rule for app.hostname.com in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I want my application app.hostname.com to redirected at https://app.hostname.com. I tried this one but it didn't work. it continuously redirecting to the same path after redirecting to https.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: I use following conif in web.config file at rool level

<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

Comment: Edit your question with additional information instead of adding a comment, that helps users to answer your question more easily.

Comment: Whatever rule you try, learn how it works internally via FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clear your browser cache and history.

try to use the below rule:

```
<rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

if there is any other rule please disable it.